# Conflict of expert opinion and correlation results

Tags: correlation, causality, count-data

The following data are related to urban accidents. The first column is fatalities and injuries resulting from accidents and the second column is police enforcement. Experts say police enforcement decrease fatalities and injuries. The expert asks how much enforcement has reduced accidents?

In the first step, I calculated the correlation between the two variables, and the correlation between these two variables was positive! The plot of the variables is also shown in the following figure:

```R
   adf <- structure(list(FI = c(23, 11, 8, 14, 30, 31, 37, 
               35, 40, 35, 22, 15, 18, 19, 16, 20, 26, 35, 
               36, 37), enf = c(2222, 788, 506, 1500, 2730, 
               3210, 3184, 2879, 2720, 2036, 1804, 1110, 
               2179, 1046, 1081, 1563, 2498, 2890, 2595, 
               2582)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), 
               class = "data.frame")
  cor(adf)
  cor(adf)
```

> ```
>        FI       enf
>   FI  1.0000000 0.8804986
>   enf 0.8804986 1.0000000
>   plot(adf$enf, adf$FI)
> ```

[image]

I gave the results to the expert, he did not accept and said that the positive correlation is because with the increase in accidents, the police send more troops into the city, and this will increase the enforcements. He is confident that increasing enforcement will reduce accidents. Is there any way to confirm or reject the expert opinion? (that seems logical). If so, how much enforcement has reduced accidents? Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: It will be difficult without an experiment or something equivalent.  What you want are two groups of places with similar accident rates and enforcement, and then you change the amount of enforcement in one group but not the other and see what happens to accidents.

Comment: It is not possible to change the amount of enforcement. Also  different places have different type accidents and different rate accident.

Comment: You will need to use the time series structure.  Sending enforcements could be seen as an intervention!